# Breeze Many to Many relationship and setting Aspect to 'setDeleted' on iteration issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, breeze

My goal is to save the user selection on a multi-selected list from KendoUIWeb-Multiselect.  I felt the easiest way to keep track of the changes to the list was just to delete everything from the many to many relationship and add the newly selected items.
When I iterate through a many to many relationship and set each entity's aspect to 'setDeleted' the iteration begins to pass 'undefined' objects through the loop.  On the surface, it seems that setting a conjunction object to delete is affecting the other objects in the list within Breeze.  Is there another way I can delete all the conjunction objects iteratively?

To Note:
I can iterate through the conjunction model with no issue if I don't call this method..

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get;set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get;set; }
    public int CourseId { get;set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get;set; }
}
```

The following code works perfectly (sets multi-selected dropdown for KendoUI multiselect):

```
    var getSelectedCourses = function () {
        var selected = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(student().studentCourses(), function(course) {
            var courseId = parseInt(course.courseId());
            selected.push(courseId);
        });
        return selected;
    };
```

The issue is manifested by the following code.  The first couple of iterations seem to go through just fine but after that '*undefined*' is passed as the 'course' parameter

```
   var removeListItems = function () {
        if (courseHasChanges()) {
            //Remove all list items
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(student().studentCourses(), function(studentCourse) {
                if (studentCourse) { //passing undefined after 2nd or 3rd iteration
                    studentCourse.entityAspect.setDeleted();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Breeze will be removing the course from the `studentCourses()` array as you are iterating through it calling `setDeleted()`.

Perhaps using `slice(0)` to clone the original `studentCourses()` array might work: (not tested)

```
var removeListItems = function () {
    if (courseHasChanges()) {
        //Remove all list items
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(student().studentCourses().slice(0), function(course) {
            if (course) { //passing undefined after 2nd or 3rd iteration
                course.entityAspect.setDeleted();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: That's right Brendan. On a different note, I was initially confused by the deletion function's parameter name, `course`. The function is actually deleting `StudentCourses`.

Comment: Sorry about that...but yes, my goal here is to delete all the StudentCourse relationships...

Comment: @David - Did adding `slice(0)` to the `arrayForEach` parameter help?